# Почему не работает селектор only-child?

Tags: css

```css
.pbta:only-child p{
    font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
        <div class="row pbta">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a class="recent" href=#>
                <img src="img/man_1.jpg" height="200" width="200" alt="J D">
               
                <div class="info d-none">
                    <p>sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem.</p>
                </div> </a>
                <H5>Jonh Doeeh</H5>
                <p>Lead Designer</p>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Может потому что это не only-child?  В вашем вопросе недостаточно информации

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/only-child - Псевдокласс :only-child применяется к дочернему элементу, только если он единственный у родителя.

Comment: Пример - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/2kzqwcqo/

Comment: В сниппете не работает, т. к. там после него пустой скрипт лежит. А почему у тебя не работает - никто не знает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ты не туда псевдокласс пристроил, это работает если он только один у родителя
псевдокласс :only-child надо присваивать самому элементу который хочешь поменять, и не обязательно, что именно параграф P единственный, а вообще единственный элемент у родителя, если даже добавить просто DIV соседом этому параграфу у тебя не сработает псевдокласс...

```css
.pbta p:only-child {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="row pbta">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <a class="recent" href=#>
      <img src="img/man_1.jpg" height="200" width="200" alt="J D">

      <div class="info d-none">
        <p>sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem.</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <H5>Jonh Doeeh</H5>
    <p>Lead Designer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы это правило распространялось только в пределах родительского контейнера .pbta

Comment: покажи какой именно  параграф ты хочешь изменить?

Comment: и еще, у тебя ошибка, в html/ у тебя div внутри тега "а", а строчный, div блочный, блочный в строчный нельзя засовывать

Comment: <div class="info d-none">
                    <p>sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem.</p>
                </div>

Comment: а если в классе ссылки указанно что display: inline-block, тогда в нее можно помещать блоки?

Comment: @sunnyrio, изменил  ответ посмотри

Comment: а что насчет display: inline-bloсk присвоенному <a> можно ли в таком случае помещать в него блочные элементы?

Comment: вообще не рекомендуется... на сколько я знаю, может в какой то момент подвести,  сейчас подробностей не вспомню, просто, когда я  изучал, там было написано, что не просто нельзя, а запрещено... я если честно и не пробовал...

Comment: в место див лучше span используй, это будет грамотней